# deserializing a generic list returns null

Tags: c#, serialization, binary-serialization

I'm de/serializing an object like so:

```
public class myClass : ISerializable
{
  public List<OType> value;

  public myClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    this.value = (List<OType>)info.GetValue("value", typeof(List<OType>));
  }

  void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("value", value, typeof(List<OType>));
  }
}
```

The object that is in the list *does* have the Serializable attribute. When serializing, no errors are thrown and the list is *never* empty, but when deserializing all of my lists are null and I'm not sure why.

I'm marking  this as answered by CQ. I was able to produce a small one off test app that does properly serialize/deserialize with the objects I'm trying to use but I still can't seem to get it to work in my production code but I suspect it's something small that I'm missing.

Comment: Perhaps OType is not serializable?

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the list is always empty to begin with, are you setting it via `myClass.value = new List<...>();` ?  Also have you saved the serialized data in both binary and xml formats so you can verify data is actually being saved?

Just a note as well, if you are using 2.0+ you don't have to implement ISerializable if you don't need to control the absolute serialization, you can change value to a public property and it will serialize on it's own.

Edit:  The following case seems to serialize and deserialize fine for me, I am posting this incase I am misunderstanding the question as a whole.

Ignoring the nasty test code, hopefully this helps a little.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class OType
    {
        public int SomeIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string SomeData { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}: {1}", SomeIdentifier, SomeData);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass : ISerializable
    {
        public List<OType> Value;

        public MyClass() {  }

        public MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.Value = (List<OType>)info.GetValue("value", typeof(List<OType>));
        }

        void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("value", Value, typeof(List<OType>));
        }
    }

...

        var x = new MyClass();

        x.Value = new OType[] { new OType { SomeIdentifier = 1, SomeData = "Hello" }, new OType { SomeIdentifier = 2, SomeData = "World" } }.ToList();

        var xSerialized = serialize(x);

        Console.WriteLine("Serialized object is {0}bytes", xSerialized.Length);

        var xDeserialized = deserialize<MyClass>(xSerialized);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", xDeserialized.Value[0], xDeserialized.Value[1]);
```

Forgot the output..

> Serialized object is 754bytes
>
> 1: Hello 2: World

Comment: I need to implement iserializable because I'm serializing some bitmaps (not shown) and you can't directly serialize a bitmap the easy way without getting a gdi error. Like I said, the list is _never_ empty. Also: I have not serialized the data in xml format. Will look into it.

Answer (score 5):

When you say that your list is null, do you mean that the list itself is null, or that it filled with null entries? If the latter, then this is a known .Net problem: see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400805/deserializing-a-class-containing-a-listt-why-is-list-initially-filled-with-nul) on the same problem.

Basically, `List<T>`s are only initialized when they are deserialized; the objects that they contain are only deserialized after the object graph has been deserialized. One way around this is to put any code which requires them in an `OnDeserialized` method, or one with an `[OnDeserializedAttribute]`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).