# Custom .NET Serialization doesn't seem to work

Tags: .net, serialization

I am using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize a collection of objects of class `A` stored in a `System::Collections::Generic::List<A^>^`. I have added the `[Serializable]` tag and have implemented `ISerializable` in class `A` (both `GetObjectData` and the special constructor). When deserializing, I find that the list is deserialized and contains the same number of elements as was serialized. However, each of these elements is a null reference.

I've checked for thrown exceptions and am sure that it is not the case. I have checked to ensure that the special constructor of the form `A(SerializationInfo ^info, StreamingContext context)` is called the correct number of times during deserialization but these re-constructed objects are *not* being referenced from the deserialized collection.

I also replaced the `System::Collections::Generic::List<A^>^` with `array<A^>^` and I'm still getting the same results. The array has the correct number of elements but each element is a null reference.

Anyone who has seen a similar problem? Any clues?

Comment: Sample broken code is always handy for these kind of questions

Comment: In your GetObjectData method are you calling ToArray() on your list?  I've made that mistake in the past when I've tried to over-think the serialization process and have gotten this same behavior.

Comment: Kleinux, I am not calling ToArray() but I did try that once to see if it would work. No such luck.

Comment: @Sam, The source code is proprietary and I can't post it here. I tried to recreate samples of the behaviour but all the samples work perfectly! I am wondering if the default serialization behaviour has been somehow modified/overridden somewhere earlier in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that any objects referred to within child objects need not have been completely deserialized immediately after a `GetValue` call. In my case, the generic `List` had not yet been completely deserialized and so contained only null references. I finally used `IDeserializationCallback` to execute code after the object graph had been completely deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like the items within your list are possibly non-serializable; if you have control over that class can you verify if it is also tagged as serializable?

Also, have you tried using an XmlFormatter to be able to visually check the serialized data to see just how it's being built?  It might provide some insight into whether the problem is occuring during serialization or deserialization.

Comment: I do have control over the class I am trying to serialize. It is tagged as [Serializable] and also implements ISerializable in order to take care of some singletons it references.

Comment: I tried the SoapFormatter (could not locate the XmlFormatter class... assumed you meant soap) and I get this: Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types

Comment: Err, yeah... got my names mixed up--I was thinking of the XmlSerializer under System.Xml.Serialization, not XmlFormatter